# ASP.NET, steps to deploy a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, code-behind

I have recently inherited an ASP.NET website to look after.

I have a copy of all the files but coming from a PHP background I am not sure how to make changes and deploy it.

After I make changes to the site I presume I need to compile it. But can I then simply copy the site onto the server or do I need to create a setup package and 'install' it over the top of the production system?

Also, where does the code-behind DLL 'sit' in the file system?

Is there a decent guide to this kind of stuff?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646551/how-to-deploy-publish-an-asp-net-website. Found in 1 minute by searching for "asp.net deploy"

Comment: I don't the the answers to that question are very good.

How do I publish over the top of an existing site?

Comment: Did you try what that other question said?

Comment: @apollo-creed, Could you (as per Uchitha's answer) provide more information about the project? e.g. Was it "installed" using an MSI (look in Add/Remove Programs if needs be for an obviou candidate), does each folder have a .aspx.cs file to accompany the .aspx on the deployed server, is there an "App_Code" folder... Basically more information on the environment/site =)

Answer (score 2):

After making changes and testing them with your local copy (I'm assuming you know how to do that), click the "Copy Web Site" button at the top of the solution explorer.  This lets you connect to a remote server (your production box, presumably) and will compare your local version of the web site to the one on the server, and flag any files that have been changed locally.  You can then update the server version so that it matches your local version.

If you're deploying the web app as a compiled DLL (instead of as uncompiled CS files), the DLL should sit in the application's \bin folder.  Even with a compiled DLL, you still need to deploy the ASPX files.

Comment: No problem.  Be careful about copying over your web.config file - usually the development and production versions of this file are different, and if so you don't want to inadvertently copy the development version over to the production box.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to go for a setup. The answers to your questions differ based on whether you are using a 'WebSite' or a 'Web Application Project'. Please answer to following and we can follow up after that;

1. Which version of .Net / ASP.Net you use? (1.1, 2.0 or newer)
2. When you open up the package in VS (Visual Studio) and right click on the top most group (solution explorer) do you see options like Build web Site, Publish Web Site?

As a long-shot just try to create an IIS web site pointed to the root of your files and see if anything comes up. If this works the work process will be;
 1. Do a change
 2. Compile
 3. Hit the web site URL and see whether it reflects

Comment: OQ said he's inheriting an existing app, so I assume it's already fully set up on his production box.  He just needs to copy over local changes.