# What is the correct procedure to deploy a Visual studio 2008 Web Application to IIS 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Currently, I have a Visual Studio 2008 Web Application using .NET Framework 3.5 and I want to deploy to my IIS 6 server. I have try to use the Build > Publish menu to publish my site to IIS 6 but it keep on giving me this error:

> Visual Web Developer does not support creating Web sites on a SharePoint Web server. See Help for more details.

So, may anyone share with me some insight on the correct procedure to deploy my Web application?

For your info: MOSS 2007 is also installed.

Comment: Yes, I can create a website under IIS but then how or what I should do to bring my Visual Studio 2008 Web application to IIS?

Comment: Possible duplicate: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646551/how-to-deploy-publish-an-asp-net-website

Comment: @Waqas, the information in that link you provided is for Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: @WaqasRaja, I tried the method of just copy the web application to the folder which I created using IIS result in "Service Unavailable" message to be displayed. Please advise.

Comment: @WaqasRaja, I solve the 'Service Unavailable' problem but end up with a Parser Error Message saying that it could not load type 'Project1._Default' where Project1 is the project name that I am performing testing based on the instruction you give me as a link.

Comment: You need to specify asp.net version to version 2.0 in iis under website properties.

Comment: @WaqasRaja, I don't get what you mean. You mention to specify the asp.net version to version 2 but later you say set version 2 for 3.5. So, should I set to version 2 or version 3.5 and where can I set?

Comment: @WaqasRaja, do correct me if I interpret wrongly, you are referring to ASP.NET 2 in the Default Web Application Properties (ASP.NET tab)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Davide,

Actually I used another command to perform the deploy.

> reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the same publish command but target a local file system folder or a network share and not IIS. Once you have got your binaries and pages in such folder deploy on iis manually with a file copy.

Comment: I try using your method but got a parser error message on the web.config file with regards to '<authentication mode="Windows"/>'

Comment: Ok so you should first fix this error then try again. probably in your web.config you have invalid content or a tag not closed...

Comment: Update: If I remove that line in the web.config file, I end up with another parser error message - could not load type 'Project1._Default' where Project1 is the project name.